# Yii2 Assest Bundle not loading CSS in the view

Tags: yii2, assets

I am facing an issue. I have custom Module in which i am trying to load CSS and JS by AppAsset but its not loading.

In my Module i have layouts folder in which i am trying to access the appasset and registering the view but its not loading. Even the asset bundle shows that assests are being loaded

Tell me what i am doing wrong. The code is as follows

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;


class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{

    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/bootstrap-reset.css',
        'css/style.css',
        'css/style-responsive.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/jquery.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

my view file is as follows

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="ThemeBucket">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">

<?php $this->registerCsrfMetaTags() ?>
<title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
<?php $this->head() ?>

<!--Core CSS -->



</head>

  <body class="login-body">


    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>

    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the css is not loaded at all and i cant see any of the css which i defined in Asset Bundle

Comment: Try to add `<?php $this->beginPage() ?>` before `<DOCTYPE>` and `<?php $this->endPage() ?>` after `</html>`

Comment: See `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php` line ~ 179, head meta tags are injected in content with function View::endPage()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `<?php $this->head() ?>` just adds a placeholder where all head meta tags, styles, scripts must be placed. 
When `<?php $this->endPage() ?>` is called it replaces placeholder with registered meta tags, styles, scripts, etc.